# js pass variables in function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, variables

I'm building my first website and I think this is a stupid question, but I'm stuck. I have an ajax call to a script that runs a query and gives an array with some information.

The ajax-call is seperated in a function.
I can't pass into the function variables with the value of an input.

With a static string/int, it works:

```
$("#searchIt").click(function(){    
    var inputbranche = $('#branche').val(); #pass the value of select
    var inputplz = $('#plz').val();         #pass the value of input
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?branche="+inputbranche+"&plz="+inputplz); //this works fine with the variables
    $('#fulllink').val(window.location.href);
    $('#sm').attr('data-url', window.location.href);
    if(searches == 0) {
        scrollTo("#topscroll");
    } else {
        scrollTo("*[data-resultnumber='1']");
    }
    searchCompanies('tischler', '44444'); //<---- here is the problem: if I use here inputbranche and inputplz, it´s not working...

});


function searchCompanies(branche, plz) {
    searches++;
    var shownbranchename = $('#branchename').val();
    $.ajax({
            url: "url/to/script",
            type: "GET",
            data:'wheretostart=0&branche='+branche+'&plz='+plz,
            success: function(data){
                var count = 0;
                if(data['success'] == 1) {
                    while(data[count] != 0 ) {
                        if(jQuery.inArray(data[count]['id'], shownIDs) == -1) {
                            var txt = "<div data-resultnumber='"+number+"' data-companyid='"+data[count]['id']+"' class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 p0'><div class='box-two proerty-item'><div class='item-thumb'><a href='property-1.html' ><img src='assets/img/demo/property-3.jpg'></a></div><div class='item-entry overflow'><h5><a href='property-1.html'> "+data[count]['companyname']+" <i class='fa fa-check-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></h5><div class='dot-hr'></div><span class='pull-left'><b> Branche :</b> "+data[count]['branches']+" </span><h3 class='pull-right'><span class='fa fa-star checked'></span><span class='fa fa-star checked'></span><span class='fa fa-star checked'></span><span class='fa fa-star'></span><span class='fa fa-star'></span></h3><p style='display: none;'>"+data[count]['shorttext']+"</p><div class='property-icon'>&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-map-marker' aria-hidden='true'></i> "+data[count]['companyzipcode']+" | <i class='fa fa-users' aria-hidden='true'></i> "+data[count]['employeecount']+" | <i class='fa fa-envelope' aria-hidden='true'></i> 355  </div></div></div></div>";
                            $("#list-type").append(txt);
                            shownIDs.push(data[count]['id']);
                        }
                        count++;
                        number++;
                        if(shownbranchename !== branche) {
                            $('#branchename').text(branche);
                        }
                    } 
                } else {
                    var txt = data['errors'];
                    $("#list-type").append(txt);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML with the search:

```
 <fieldset>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branche">Branche:</label><br>
                    <select name="branche" id="branche" class="form-control" title="Branche">
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "architekten") {echo "selected";} ?> value="architekten">Architekten</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "dachdecker") {echo "selected";} ?> value="dachdecker">Dachdecker</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "geruestbauer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="geruestbauer">Gerüstbauer</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "klempner") {echo "selected";} ?> value="klempner">Klempner</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "maler_und_lackierer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="maler_und_lackierer">Maler und Lackierer</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "maurer_und_betonbauer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="maurer_und_betonbauer">Maurer und Betonbauer</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "metallbauer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="metallbauer">Metallbauer</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "Ofen-_und_Luftheizungsbauer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="Ofen-_und_Luftheizungsbauer">Ofen- und Luftheizungsbauer</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "schornsteinfeger") {echo "selected";} ?> value="schornsteinfeger">Schornsteinfeger</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "strassenbauer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="strassenbauer">Straßenbauer</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "tischler") {echo "selected";} ?> value="tischler">Tischler</option>
                         <option <?php if($_GET['branche'] == "zimmerer") {echo "selected";} ?> value="zimmerer">Zimmerer</option>
                     </select>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="plz">Postleitzahl:</label>  
                    <input type="number" id="plz" name="plz" class="form-control" <?php if($_GET['plz'] != null) {$temp = $_GET['plz']; echo "value='$temp'";} else {echo "placeholder='Postleitzahl'";} ?>>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">  
               <button type="button" id="searchIt" class="button btn largesearch-btn" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>  
     </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Here is the php code, hopefully this helps...

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
session_start();
$return = array();
/* PHP lookup: Looks up the matching Companies in the DB */
require_once ('../global_konfi.php');
require_once ('../functions/functions.php');
$pdo = new  pdo ("mysql:host=dddd; dbname=" . $mysql['database'], 
$mysql['user'], $mysql['password']);
if(brancheIsBranche($_GET['branche']) == true) {
    $plz = $_GET['plz'];
    $limitstart = $_GET['wheretostart'];
    $perpage = "15";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as anzahl FROM handwerksbetriebe WHERE general_branche = :branche AND general_visible = 1 AND general_state = 1 AND assignment_zipcoderange LIKE :zipcode LIMIT $limitstart, $perpage");
    $statement->bindValue(':branche', $_GET['branche']);       
    $statement->bindValue(':zipcode', "%;$plz;%", PDO::PARAM_STR);       
    if ($statement->execute()) { 
        $row = $statement->fetch();
        if ($row['anzahl'] >= 1) {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM handwerksbetriebe WHERE general_branche = :branche AND general_visible = 1 AND general_state = 1 AND assignment_zipcoderange LIKE :zipcode LIMIT $limitstart, $perpage"); #statemetn vorbereiten
            $statement->bindValue(':branche', $_GET['branche'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
            $statement->bindValue(':zipcode', "%;$plz;%", PDO::PARAM_STR);  
            $statement->execute();
            $count = 0;
            $temp = array();
            while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                $temp = [
                    'id' => $row['general_id'],
                    'shorttext' => $row['general_shorttext'],
                    'companyname' => $row['general_title'],
                    'verified' => $row['general_verified'],
                    'assignmentcount' => $row['general_assignmentcount'],
                    'employeecount' => $row['general_employeecount'],
                    'averagerating' => $row['general_averagerating'],
                    'companyzipcode' => $row['contact_zipcode'],
                    'branches' => $row['general_branche'],
                ];
                array_push($return, $temp);
                $count++;
            }
            $return['errors'] = "0";
            $return['success'] = "1";
        } else {
        $return['errors'] = "noexecute";
        $return['success'] = "0";
        }

    } else {
        $return['errors'] = "noexecute";
        $return['success'] = "0";
    }
} else { 
$return['errors'] = "norealinput";
$return['success'] = "0";
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: What you mean by "can't pass"?

Comment: Maybe you should have jQuery format your data for you and pass it as an object. `data:{wheretostart:0,branche:branche,plz:plz},`

Comment: This looks fine. Please elaborate on “it’s not working”.

Comment: if I call the function like this: `searchCompanies('tischler', '44444');` , it works. If I call it like this: `searchCompanies(inputbranche , inputplz);` , it doesnt work

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML.

Comment: You have a `success` function defined for the AJAX call, but perhaps the call is failing?  Try adding an `error` function as well to handle what might happen if it doesn't work.  Something like `error: function (jqXHR, status, err) { console.log(status, err);  }`

Comment: If I Use `searchCompanies('tischler', '44444');`, it works. So I dont thik that the php script is failing? @ErikGrosskurth I've added the php code

Comment: Is the click event in the document.ready function? See my answer below. wrap any dom events in that to ensure that jQuery will only look for them once the dom is rendered

Comment: Yes it's inside. What I don't understand is that it woks fine without the variables

Comment: Im getting this in my console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` Im quering the id and its correctly shown in the `data-companyid`

Comment: And I have added my php code

Comment: Are you making an async call to populate the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive switched the place of the function call of the ajax. Now it works. Don't know why:

```
$("#searchIt").click(function(){

        var inputbranche = $('#branche').val();
        var inputplz = $('#plz').val();
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?branche="+inputbranche+"&plz="+inputplz);
        searchCompanies(inputbranche, inputplz);
        $('#fulllink').val(window.location.href);
        $('#sm').attr('data-url', window.location.href);
        if(searches == 0) {
        scrollTo("#topscroll");
        } else {
        scrollTo("*[data-resultnumber='1']");
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the click event inside the

```
$(document).ready() {//click event here}
function searchCompanies(var1, var2) {//...code}
```

so that the dom is rendered and jQuery can find the HTML elements by ID.

If you have done this already, please post more code (specifically the HTML and JS) so we may better help with your issue

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  context: {key: "1"},
  success: function(data){
   const contextValue = this.key;
  }
});
```

Make sure you don't use arrow functions `() => {...}` when handling `$.ajax` events as it'll give `this` a different meaning to what you'd expect - arrow functions won't modify `this`, which in this particular case this is a desired effect.

Comment: There isn’t no need to use `context`.